# Defining functions from expressions of variable lengths

Tags: function-construction

I have a list of symbols that I have defined using

```
d = Table[Symbol["d" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}]
```

giving

```
d = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5}
```

where n = 5 in this case.  I use this as part of an argument to an interpolation, giving me

```
Vchamber = 0.111549 d1 - 0.101842 d2 + 0.857554 d3 - 1.09366 d4 + 2.24236 d5
```

Now I want to define a function that gives something like

```
 fVchamber[d1_,d2_,d3_d4_,d5_] := 0.111549 d1 - 0.101842 d2 + 0.857554 d3 - 1.09366 d4 + 2.24236 d5
```

Now, n is variable.  Hence, the argument list is variable, as is the expression Vchamber. I was hoping that something like

```
 fVchamber[d__]:=Function[d,Vchamber]
```

would work but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?  I have looked for answers but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Could you perhaps just work with lists instead of introducing those symbols?  `fVchamber[dlist_] := {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5} . dlist`

Comment: This is just one form that I have.  I have expressions that are more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
fVchamber = Function[Evaluate@d, Evaluate@Vchamber]
```

So first, when you define a `Function`, you don't need a definition like

```
fVchamber[d__]:=...
```

Second, `Function` apparently `Holds` the arguments, so you need to make sure they are evaluated. After the above definition, this seems to work:

```
In[10]:= fVchamber[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Out[10]= -0.101842
```

Comment: See, for example the [example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) where they use a similar construct to set `f` equal to the pure function