# Solution of a function that is in a variable

Tags: function-construction

If I want to get the solution for a simple function, e.g. a^x, I can use:

```
a = 2;
Function[x, a^x][2]
```

However, if I have the function in a variable, I can't get it to work:

```
a = 2;
func = a^x
Function[x, func][2]
```

Similarly, this doesn't work as wished, which is that the last line provides the result if 2 is put into x:

```
a = 2;
func = a^x;
der = D[func, x]
Function[x, der][2]
```

Comment: `Function` is `HoldAll` so `Function[x, #][2] &[func]`, let me find a duplicate.

Comment: duplicates?: [14686](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14686/5478), [22033](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22033/5478) related: [10067](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10067/5478), [40445](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40445/5478), [31985](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31985/5478)

Comment: Intersting. But this doesn't work: # &[2] &[func]

Comment: Because it isn't what I've suggested ;)

Comment: @Kuba Sure! You didn't suggest it, I was just wondering whether this works as well.

Comment: @kuba. It seems to me that the answers given cover what this questions ask.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry, wasn't reading carefully, you are right, the answer is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html),

```
a = 2;
func = a^x;
Function[x, func][2]
Function[x, Evaluate@func][2]
(* 2^x *)
(* 4 *)
```

and

```
a = 2;
func = a^x;
der = D[func, x];
Function[x, der][2]
Function[x, Evaluate@der][2]
(* 2^x Log[2] *)
(* 4 Log[2] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, it seems the following does not work: Evaluate[#] &[2]